# How can I get a variable to read a file and check how many times it contains a word?

Tags: java, file

I wanted "szSearch" to read the WORDLIST.txt file and check how many times the user's word appears in the file. So for example,

What word are you searching for? **long**
Searching the file...
The word long appears 24 times in the file WORDLIST.txt.

--- File End ---

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //creating scanner objects which  will be used to read in the file
    FileReader file = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    
    //declaring variables and assigning values
    Scanner szKeyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    String szWord = "";
    String szSearch;
    int iCount = 0;
    
    try
    {
        //open the file WORDLIST.txt using the Scanner and File classes
        //File object used to open and store the file
        //Scanner object will be used to read through the file object
        file = new FileReader("WORDLIST.txt");
        
        //needed for methods
        br = new BufferedReader(file);
        
        //ask the user what word they're searching for
        System.out.print("What word are you searching for? ");
        szWord = szKeyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Searching the file...");
        
        szSearch = br.readLine();
        
        //method to count how many times that word occurs in the WORDLIST.txt file
        while (szSearch.contains(szWord))
        {
            iCount = iCount + 1;
        }
        
        System.out.println("The word " + szWord  + " appears " + iCount + " times in the file WORDLIST.txt.");
        
    }//end try
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error - Writing to File: " + e);
    }//end catch
    finally
    {
        //close scanner
        szKeyboard.close();

        //finally runs regardless of wheter the try has worked
        //the aim of a finally is to tidy up any loose ends
        //if the contents within read is not equal to nothing i.e. it was possible to open and read
        //close the file (try) if the file was not loaded catch the exception IOException
        try
        {
            br.close();
    `your text` }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error - Closing BufferReader: " + e);
        }

        try
        {
            file.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error - closing FileReader: " + e);
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n--- File End ---");
    }//end try catch finally`
    
}//end class
```

---

This is what I tried doing but when I run it, it says:

What word are you searching for? **long**
Searching the file...
The word long appears 0 times in the file WORDLIST.txt.

--- File End ---

Comment: I would do `while ((szSearch = br.readLine()) != null)`.

Comment: Your code reads only the first line of the file: `szSearch = br.readLine();` . The body of your `while` loop contains no line that will read from `br`. To fix it, you need `szSearch = br.readLine();` inside the body of the while loop. In addition, you need to change the condition of the `while` loop to exit when the end of the file is reached, not dependent on whether `szSearch` contains the word being sought.

Comment: By the way, if the first line of the file contains the word being sought, your code could go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the while you have with this block of code, it probably requires some tweaking as I didn't test the code, but the logic I think solves it.

```
while ((strCurrentLine = objReader.readLine ())! = null) {
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(strCurrentLine.split(" "));
    iCount += words.stream().hasMatch(w -> w.equals(szWord)).count();
}
```